# Check each cell for non-zero value in a matrix and apply function from non-zero value cell upto last cell in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, apply

I've a matrix in R that looks like this:
0
0
1
0
2
0
4

```
    #Create Matrix
    value <- c(0,0,1,0,2,0,4)
    dff = matrix(value)
    #Calculate Mean 
    mean(dff[,1])
```

gives 1 as the answer, but I want the mean to be 1+0+2+0+4/5 = 7/5 = 1.4
So, essentially I want the algo to find the first non-zero value(that is 1 in this case) and use that as a starting point for the series (1,0,2,0,4).

This query here - [Apply function to each cell of matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676877/apply-function-to-each-cell-of-matrix-in-r) - is a similar to what I wish to do, but I can't seem to apply it to this context. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `mean(tail(value, -(which(value!=0)[1]-1)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert matrix to vector, get index of first non-zero value, subset and then take `mean`

```
temp <- c(dff)
mean(temp[which.max(temp != 0) : length(temp)])
#[1] 1.4
```

Comment: Or without converting to vector: `mean(dff[which.max(dff[,1] != 0) : length(dff)])`

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah and @patL for your prompt answers! There were several columns so I used the following code to loop through each. I had to find out the mean and SD, among other things. It worked!   `M1 = matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = ncol(sku4b2t))` 
`for (i in 1:ncol(sku4b2t))`
`{`
 `M1[1,i] = mean(sku4b2t[which.max(sku4b2t[,1] != 0) : length(sku4b2t[,1]),i])`
  `M1[2,i] = sd(sku4b2t[which.max(sku4b2t[,1] != 0) : length(sku4b2t[,1]),i])`
}`